# Click event executes both click and hover event handler even when the click event handler unbinds all handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I'm coding a tic tac toe game. After the user chooses who starts and whether to use X or O, he can hover over an empty grid and X or O would appear to show the user that he can move there. When the user clicks on the grid he wants to make the move on, the X or O would stay there and the move would be permanent. Currently I have this working but in a really strange way. Here's the code:

```
$('td').hover(moveHover);
$('td').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).html('');
});
$('td').click(move);

function move(){
    $(this).unbind();
}   

function moveHover(){
    if (xO === 'X'){
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-times fa-5x"></i>');
        $('td i').css('color', '#ccc');
    }
    if (xO === 'O'){
        $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-5x"></i>');
        $('td i').css('color', '#ccc');
    }       
}
```

The click event handler only unbinds any click event handlers from the element. It's not actually appending the X or O icon as a child element. However when I click on an empty grid, it does append an icon anyway. Here's the [link](http://codepen.io/edward-hong/pen/EKVeOG) all of the code and if you want to try it yourself. I was wondering how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do right now is appending on hover and removing on unhover:

```
$('td').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).html('');
});
```

Once you click, you already hovered, so the X or O is appended. **But** you did not yet unhover (mouseleave), so it is not removed yet. As you now click and therefore unbind everything, you unbind mouseleave aswell, so it is never removed again.

That's actually a pretty smart solution.

Thumbs up for the graphics aswell!

Comment: Thanks to be honest I stumbled on it. Originally I had the move function be the same as the moveHover function and also `$(this).unbind();` at the end of it. But when I tested it, clicking on a grid would produce 2 X's or O's. So then I tried just having `$(this).unbind();` in the function and that's how I got the code looking like it is now.

Answer (score 0):

That was a CSS issue, the code uses [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) CSS styling, I have attached that code in a snippet here (click Run button below), and see it's working. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var xO = '';
  var xOClass = '';
  var whoStart = '';
  var option1 = $('.option1').html();
  var option2 = $('.option2').html();
  var choice = $('.choice').html();

  $('.choose').click(choose);

  function choose(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('.choice h2').text() === 'Who starts?') {
      whoStart = $(this).children('p').text().substr(0, $(this).children('p').text().indexOf(' '));
      $('.option1 p, .option2 p').empty();
      $('.choice h2').remove();
      $('.choice').prepend('<a href="#" class="restart"><h2>Restart Game</h2></a>');
      $('.restart').hover(function() {
        $('.restart h2').css('color', '#000');
      });
      $('.restart').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.restart h2').css('color', '#777');
      });
      $('.restart').click(restart);
      $('.option1 a').remove();
      $('.option2 a').remove();
      $('.choice').css('height', '100px');
      $('td').hover(moveHover);
      $('td').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).html('');
      });
      $('td').click(move);
    }
    if ($('.choice h2').text() === 'X or O?') {
      xO = $(this).children('p').text().substr(13);
      $('.choice h2').text('Who starts?');
      $('.option1 i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-laptop');
      $('.option1 p').text('Computer starts');
      $('.option2 i').removeClass('fa-circle-o').addClass('fa-user');
      $('.option2 p').text('Player starts');
    }
  }

  function restart(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.option1').empty().html(option1);
    $('.option2').empty().html(option2);
    $('.choice').empty().html(choice);
    $('.choose').click(choose);
    $('td').unbind();
    $('td').empty();
  }

  function move() {
    $(this).unbind();
  }

  function moveHover() {
    console.log(xO, this);
    if (xO === 'X') {
      $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-times fa-5x"></i>');
      $('td i').css('color', '#ccc');
    }
    if (xO === 'O') {
      $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-5x"></i>');
      $('td i').css('color', '#ccc');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
h1,
.col-xs-4,
.col-xs-12 {
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: #777;
}

a {
  color: #777;
}

td {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

table {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.middle {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #777, 0 1px 0 #777;
}

.center {
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #777, 1px 0 0 #777;
}

.middle.center {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #777, 0 1px 0 #777, -1px 0 0 #777, 1px 0 0 #777;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  min-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 option1">
      <a href="#" class="choose">
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-5x"></i>
        <p>I want to be X</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 choice">
      <h2>X or O?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 option2">
      <a href="#" class="choose">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-5x"></i>
        <p>I want to be O</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="top left"></td>
          <td class="top center"></td>
          <td class="top right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="middle left" id=></td>
          <td class="middle center"></td>
          <td class="middle right"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="bottom left"></td>
          <td class="bottom center"></td>
          <td class="bottom right"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```